# SharePoint .wsp retraction error

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, deployment, solution-package, solution-deployment

I am **deploying** a solution by Visual Studio.
I get the error during **Retraction**:

> The solution does not have a WSP file associated with it.

I tried to do IISRESET and also to restart the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
remove-spsolution -identity {name of wsp file.wsp} -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

1. Open the debug/release folder and make sure a WSP file is generated
2. Open central admins -> system settings -> farm solutions. If a solution with the name exists, then retract and remove it.
3. Check log files